# What do you test with Unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing

I am new to unit testing. Suppose I am building a web application. How do I know what to test? All the examples that you see are some sort of basic sum function that really has no real value, or at least I've never written a function to add to inputs and then return!

So, my question...on a web application, what are the sort of things that need tested?

I know that this is a broad question but anything will be helpful. I would be interested in links or anything that gives real life examples as opposed to concept examples that don't have any real life usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your code, especially the bits where you have complex logic with loops, conditionals, etc, and ask yourself: **How do I know if this works?**

If you need to change the complex logic to take into account other corner cases then how do you know that the changes you introduce don't break the existing cases?  This is precisely what unit testing is intended to address.

So, to answer your question about how it applies to web applications: suppose you have some code that lays out the page differently depending on the browser.  One of your customers refuses to upgrade from IE6 and insists that you support that.  So you unit test your layout code by simulating the connection string from IE6 and checking that the layout is what you expect.

A customer tells you they've found a security hole where using a particular cookie will give you administrator access.  How do you know that you've fixed the bug and it doesn't happen again?  Create a unit test for it, and run the unit tests on a daily basis so that you get an early warning if it fails.

You discover a bug where users with accents in their names get corrupted in the database.  Abstract out the webform input from the database layer and add unit tests to ensure that (eg) UTF8 encoded data is stored in the database correctly and can be retrieved.

You get the idea.  Anywhere where part of the process has a well-defined input and output is ideal for unit testing.  Anything that doesn't is ideal for refactoring until it is well defined.  Take a look at projects such as WebUnit, HTMLUnit, XMLUnit, CSSUnit.

Answer (score 2):

The first part of testing is to write testable applications. Separate out as much functionality as possible from the UI. Refactor into smaller methods. Learn about dependency injection, and try using that to create methods that can take simple, throw-away input that produces known (and therefor testable) results. Look at mocking tools.

Infrastructure and data layer code is easiest to test.

Look at behavior-driven testing as well as test-driven design. For my money, behavior testing is better than pure unit testing; you can follow use-cases, so that tests match against expected usage patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing means testing any unit of work, the smallest units of work are methods and functions., The art of unit testing is to define tests for a function that cannot just be checked by inspection, what unit test aims at is to test every possible functional requirement of a method.

Consider for example you have a login function, then there could be following tests that you could write for failures:
1. Does the function fail on empty username and password
2. Does the function fail on the correct username but the wrong password
3. Does the function fail on the correct password but the wrong username

The you would also write tests that the function would pass:
1. Does the function pass on correct username and password

This is just a basic example but this is what unit testing attempts to achieve, testing out things that may have been overlooked during development.

Then there is a purist approach too where a developer is first supposed to write tests and then the code to pass those tests (aka test driven development).

Resources:
http://devzone.zend.com/article/2772
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest.html

Comment: +1 for the really good links. I like the devzone.zend.com article the best.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to TDD, may I suggest a quick trip into the world of BDD? My experience is that the language really helps people pick up TDD more quickly. Particularly, I point you at this article, in which Dan North suggests "what to test":

http://blog.dannorth.net/introducing-bdd/

Note for transparency: I may be heavily involved in the BDD movement.

Regarding the classes to unit test in a web-app, I'd consider starting with controllers, domain objects if they have complex behaviour, and anything called "service", "manager", "helper" or "util". Please also try renaming any classes like this so that they are less generic and actually say what they do. Classes called "calculator" or "converter" are also good candidates, and you'll probably find more in the same package / folder.

There are a couple of good books which could help you too:

- Martin Fowler, "Refactoring"
- Michael Feathers, "Working Effectively with Legacy Code"

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you start out saying, "How do I test my web app?" that is biting off a lot at once, and it's going to be hard to see unit testing as providing any kind of benefit. I got into unit testing by starting with small pieces that were isolated, then writing libraries test-first, and only then building whole applications that were testable.

Generally a web app has a domain model, it has data access objects that do queries on a database and return domain objects, it has services that call the data access objects, and it has controllers that accept http requests and call the services.

Tests for the controllers will check that they call the right service method with the right parameters. Service objects can be mocks injected during test setup.

Tests for the services will check that they call the right data access objects and perform whatever logic they need to be performing. Data access objects can be mocks injected during test setup.

Tests for the data access objects will check that they perform the right database operation (query or update or whatever) by checking the contents of the database before and after. For dao tests you'll need a database, and a tool like DBUnit to pre-populate it before the test. Also your domain objects' getters and setters will get exercised with this test so you won't need a separate test for them.

Tests for the domain model will check that whatever domain logic you have encoded in them works (Sometimes you may not have any). If you design your domain model so it is not coupled to the database then the more logic you put in the domain model the better because it's easy to test. You shouldn't need any mocks for these tests.

Answer (score 0):

For a web app the kind of tests you need to do are slightly different. Unit tests are tests which test a particular component of your program. For a web app, you would need to test that forms accept/reject the right inputs, that all links point to the right place, that it can cope with unexpected inputs etc. I'd have a look at Selenium if I were you, I've used it extensively in testing a number of sites: [Selenium HQ](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience of testing web apps, but speaking generally: you unit test the smallest 'chunks' of your program possible. That means you test each function on an individual basis. Anything on a larger scale becomes an integration test.

Of course, there are going to be methods so simple that its not worth your time to write a test for them, but on the whole aim to test as great a proportion of your code as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A rule of thumb is that if it is not worth testing it is not worth writing.

However, some things are very difficult to test, so you have the do some cost benefit analysis on what you test. If you initially aim for 70% code coverage, you will be on the right track.